# cannot ssh into a manually created google cloud instance

Tags: gcloud

i manually created a google cloud instance so the root partition could be sized to 100 GB as opposed to the default 10GB that google sets. the instance starts up (i can see it running on the google dashboard) however i cannot ssh in via the google console or by using gcloud compute .

**My suspicion is:**

1. that a manually created instance may not have started sshd.
2. that a manually created instance may not have started network
   services.

Is there a way to check if network services is running using gcloud compute?

Is there a way to check if sshd is running using gcloud compute?

If either of these services are not running how can i start them remotely using gcloud compute?
tyia

Comment: Can you access the instance's Serial Port output? Can you elaborate further on "manually created" meaning? When using custom images, the next [requirements and recomendations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images) must be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

The ssh configuration needs to be set before packaging the custom image. 
However you can achieve your initial aim of creating a VM with a 100GB root disk in the following way. 
Create a new Disk, choose "image" as Source Type and select one of the Linux images. 
Type in the desired size of your disk in GB and create the disk. 
Now you can choose this disk when creating a new VM.